# How to do custom filtering in excel

Tags: excel

Please see my [sample excel sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vie7RodqTMH3nV8ba6XTNsh9gXP9MGqnkjzYRiw2nwY/edit?usp=sharing/). I am trying to filter out tasks by projects. For example if i filter Project A then i would want to see all the tasks that falls under this project.

How is this possible in excel?

please help.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simple.  You have left gaps in column **A**.  While this may improve readability for humans, it creates difficulty for AutoFilter.

Fill-down cells **A3** through **A5** with *Project A*  Then format these cells so the color of the font matches the interior color of the cell *(this makes the text invisible and restores your visual effect)*

Finally apply the AutoFilter and all the correct rows will be visible!

[image]